# Why is the drawn UIBezierPath positioned in the bottom right without specifying a central position in CAShapeLayer?

Tags: swift, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I tried to centralize `UIBezierPath` in a superview, but the `UIBezierPath` is positioned at the bottom right, not at the center.

I set the value of `anchorPoint` to `(0.5, 0.5)`, `position` `self.view.center` or `self.view.frame.width / 2`, but the `UIBezierPath` is not centered.

```
import UIKit

/* ViewSection */
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Toolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var UIToolbarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBAction func UIToolbarButtonItem(_ sender: Any) {
        let objectFramePath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y:  0, width: 150, height: 150), byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 39.5, height: 39.5))

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) 
        shapeLayer.position = self.view.center
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.path = objectFramePath.cgPath

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: Try to call `view.layer.layoutSublayers` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor doesn’t work because the new layer doesn’t have a `frame`. If you set that, it works:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:  0, width: 150, height: 150)
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 39.5, height: 39.5))

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
shapeLayer.frame = rect
shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

---

Alternatively, you can just set the origin of the `path`:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
let origin = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX - size.width / 2,
                     y: view.bounds.midY - size.height / 2)

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size), byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 39.5, height: 39.5))

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

---

By the way, notice that I do not reference `center`, because [as the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) say, “The center point is specified in points in the coordinate system of its superview.”

Always use `bounds` (and if you need the center of that, the `midX` and `midY` of the `bounds`), because that will always be in the coordinate system of the view in question. In this case it just happens to not make much of a difference, but we should note that the middle of the `bounds` and the `center` within the superview are two completely different things.

Comment: Thank you to your kindness.